# Contact Form 7 Style different for "Select" field than other fields

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a basic contact form 7 on my site that works fine. I just tried to add a Select field to the form though, and the style of the field is different than the rest. It's white and opaque vs. dark and transparent. I'd like to edit the style of the Select field to be more like the rest of the form, so I'm trying to find what the default style is for the rest of the form so I can copy it.

[image]

Is the default style determined by my theme? If so, how can I find it?

Does the Select field look different for some other reason not style-related? I added it in exactly the same as I did all other fields, with no extra styling whatsoever in the theme, custom CSS, or additional settings areas.

Here's the form code in CF7:

```
[text* title placeholder "First Name*"] 
[text* last-name placeholder "Last Name*"] 
[email* email-text placeholder "Your Email*"]
[tel* phone-number-code placeholder "Phone Number"]
[textarea commentquestion 4x10 placeholder "How Can We Help You?"]
[select how-did-you-hear "How did you hear about us?" "YouTube" "Google" "Facebook" "Referred by someone" "Other"]

[submit "Send"]
```

Thank you!

Comment: I can help if you post the link.

Comment: Thanks! The link to the site where the form is kept I'm assuming? It's https://www.wholesalehacker.com. Not sure if it's relevant but the part of the homepage on the site where the form is shown is from the Slider Revolution plugin. On the Slider Revolution plugin where that part is built, I just have a call to the CF7 in question

Comment: Do you require something like this? https://nimb.ws/Ox4WIc https://nimb.ws/0YniCh

Comment: Yesssss that's exactly what I'm looking for! Please share your wisdom haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current dark styles are being applied from `slider-form` but it does not include the custom styles for the select element, which is being applied by the theme by default.

You can target the select element of the specific form using the following

```
#wpcf7-f8-p6635-o1 select.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-select {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.11);
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

Additionally, If you want to style the option elements

```
#wpcf7-f8-p6635-o1 select.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-select option {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Brilliant my friend. Thank you! Any idea why the style for other elements is coming from slider-form, but the select element is coming from the theme? Seems weird

Comment: Because the Custom CSS for the input elements is set but not for the selec: https://nimb.ws/pBPuT6